Seeking a Function in ARM64 Linux Kernel for Splitting Huge Pages, Similar to change_page_attr_set_clr in x86
I am developing a module for the ARM64 Linux kernel (version 4.19) that requires fine-grained control over page attributes, particularly concerning the management of huge pages (e.g., 2MB or larger). In the x86 architecture, I have utilized the change_page_attr_set_clr function to dynamically modify page attributes, where a notably useful feature is its force_split parameter. This parameter allows for the forced splitting of huge pages (e.g., splitting a 2MB page into multiple 4KB standard pages) to apply attribute changes to individual smaller pages without affecting the entire huge page.
static int change_page_attr_set_clr(unsigned long *addr, int numpages, \
                    pgprot_t mask_set, pgprot_t mask_clr, \
                    int force_split, int in_flag, \
                    struct page **pages);

I am looking for a function or method within the ARM64 Linux kernel that offers similar functionality. My primary goals are to:

Execute splitting operations on huge pages to revert them to standard-sized pages.

I understand that the ARM64 architecture differs from x86 in aspects of memory management, including the structure and handling of page tables. Therefore, I'm seeking insights into mechanisms or APIs in ARM64 that support functionalities akin to the force_split feature, enabling similar memory management operations.
I have no specific requirements regarding the kernel version, but a recent stable version is preferred. If specific kernel configurations or compile options are needed, please also mention them.

It looks like madvise(MADV_NOHUGEPAGE) does this from user space, so you could start by looking at the code for sys_madvise and seeing what it ends up calling.
